# Custom meta box save values issues - Deprecated: Function ereg() and more

Tags: php, functions, metabox

I'm a WP theme dev nobie and I have problems with saving custom meta boxes values.

I found some tutorial where its explained how to do this.

I have included a file called custom-meta-boxes-save.php within my functions.php with the following code:

```
<?php 
function save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    global $post, $new_meta_boxes, $page_settings, $blogroll, $post_settings, $team_info, $slide_info, $meta_box_groups;


    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) { //Prevents the metaboxes from being overwritten while quick editing.
        return $post_id;
    }

    if( ereg('/\edit\.php', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) { //Detects if the save action is coming from a quick edit/batch edit.
        return $post_id;
    }
    foreach($meta_box_groups as $group) {
        foreach($group as $meta_box) {

            if(isset($_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_noncename'])){
                if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_noncename'], $meta_box['name'].'-meta' )) {
                    error_log(print_r($meta_box, TRUE).'{err_end}');
                    return $post_id;
                }
            }

            if ( isset($_POST['post_type']) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
                if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ))
                    return $post_id;
            } else {
                if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
                    return $post_id;
            }

            if(isset($_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_value'])){
                $data = $_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_value'];
            }

            if(get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value') == "") 
                add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', $data, true);
            elseif($data != get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true))
                update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', $data);
            elseif($data == "" || $data == $meta_box['std'] )
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true));

        } // end foreach
    } // end foreach
} // end save_postdata

add_action('save_post', 'save_postdata');
?>
```

After hitting  publish for posts and pages I get a number of errors when my wp_debug is turned on:

```
Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in /home/creat/domains/tester.net/public_html/re/wp-content/themes/rev2/includes/custom-meta-boxes-save.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: data in /home/creat/domains/tester.net/public_html/re/wp-content/themes/rev2/includes/custom-meta-boxes-save.php on line 41

Notice: Undefined variable: data in /home/creat/domains/tester.net/public_html/re/wp-content/themes/rev2/includes/custom-meta-boxes-save.php on line 43

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/creat/domains/tester.net/public_html/re/wp-content/themes/rev2/includes/custom-meta-boxes-save.php:41) in /home/creative/domains/ctproject.net/public_html/sa2/wp-admin/post.php on line 233

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/creat/domains/tester.net/public_html/re/wp-content/themes/rev2/includes/custom-meta-boxes-save.php:41) in /home/creative/domains/ctproject.net/public_html/sa2/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1178
```

Help much needed as my deadline is VERY CLOSE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Replace

```
ereg('/\edit\.php', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

with

```
preg_match('/edit.php/',  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

And also change

```
if(isset($_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_value'])){
    $data = $_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_value'];
}
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_value'])){
    $data = $_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_value'];
}
else
    $data = "";
```